# C Preprocessor Guards?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor, guard

I am working on a `C` project, and am trying to use pre-processor guards as can be used in C++:

```
#ifndef CONFIG_H
#define CONFIG_H

... exciting stuff in C ....

#endif
```

Including this in my source appears to have no effect in Visual Studio, as when I include a given file, such as `Config.h`, in multiple files, the compiler gives me the following errors:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: _OPCodes already defined in lib.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: _OPTotal already defined in lib.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: _RegCodes already defined in lib.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: _RegTotal already defined in lib.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: _UDSTotal already defined in lib.obj
```

Could anyone give me any pointers (no pun intended) on this, please?

Comment: `#define CONFIG_G` should be `#define CONFIG_H`

Comment: @maditya Sorry, it's 3 in the morning, it was a typo in my post. Fixed now and still not working.

Comment: When you say "including this in my source," you mean you put the include guard in the header, not in the `.cpp` files, right? In any case, try putting `#pragma once` in there as well, just to see what happens.

Comment: I suspect AProgrammer's answer is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The guards will prevent defining things twice in a compilation unit. They will not prevent defining the same thing in different compilation units.  And the linker messages indicates that it is what occurs `_OPCodes` for instance is defined in `lib` and in `main`.

Usually, a header should have only declarations for functions and global variables, corresponding definitions would be provided in one of the source files.

(See for instance [What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration) for more information)

Comment: Thank you that was the answer to my problem. I was (stupidly) defining stuff in my `.h` file. Move them to a `.c`, and my problems disappeared.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: this is based on the original post, which had a typo. It's NOT the OP's real problem, apparently.

You've given your guards two different names. They must match.

```
#ifndef CONFIG_H
#define CONFIG_H  // not CONFIG_G!
```

Comment: Sorry, it's 3 in the morning, it was a typo in my post. Fixed now and still not working.

Comment: Try adding `#pragma once` just for kicks to see if that fixes it. If not, then your problem is not in this header file. If so, you might have your `#endif` in the wrong place or some such thing. In any case, adding `#pragma once` can't hurt anything, and it miiiiiight speed up compilation just a tiiiiiiiiny bit. (Probably not, though.)

Answer (score 2):

```
#ifndef CONFIG_H
#define CONFIG_G

... exciting stuff in C ....

#endif
```

its a typo because of that you are getting 'already defined error'

in your header file you are defining CONFIG_G instead of CONFIG_H , so from the next source file the #ifndef CONFIG_H is true so it is again including the same contents

Comment: Sorry, it's 3 in the morning, it was a typo in my post. Fixed now and still not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you have renamed any files you should remove them from the solution and re-add them. Sometimes Visual Studio is a bit weird with this and they will cause linker errors when left in.

Make sure to do a rebuild.

You may also have accidentally included a `.cpp` file instead of a `.h` file. Double check all the includes just in case.